# Different numbers, different dates, number of calls by hour each day 0 where absent

Tags: sas

I am trying to add hours 0-23 where calls have not occurred on a particular number and a particular date and set it to zero. For example, my data contains following

```
----------

callNumber Date Hour Calls NextHour LastHour

--------------------------------------------

883  26thSep2019  7 14  .  .
885  25thSep2019  5  5  2  .
885  25thSept2019 2  4  1  5
885  25thSept2019 1  3  .  2
885  28thAug2019  3  5  7  .


----------
```

In this case for the number 883 on the date 26th sept I want to add Hour 0,1,2,3,4...23 and set number of calls as zero. In the second number 885 I want to group by callNumber Date and Hour. If the hour is not present then I want to add the hour and set the calls for that hour to zero.

I tried the following code but it works fine only only to some extent capturing only the first instance

```
data settingHours;
set stage3;
by callDialed eventDate ;
if LastHour = . then
    do 
        Hour = Hour;
        Calls = Calls;
    output;
    end;
    do i=0 to (Hour-1);
        Hour = i;
        Calls = 0;
    output;
    end;
 if NextHour = .  then do j=Hour+2 to 23;
    Hour = j;
    Calls = 0;
    output;
    end;
 if NextHour > . & LastHour > . then
        do
            Hour = Hour;
            Calls = Calls;
        output;
        end;

run;
```

the result I am expecting is

```
----------
callNumber Date Hour Calls        
--------------------------

883 26thSep2019   0 0
883 26thSep2019   1 0
883 26thSep2019   2 0
883 26thSep2019   7 14
----------
```

Comment: What happened to hours 3, 4, 5, 6?

Comment: In your input data `25thSep2019` (3 character month) and `25thSept2019` (4 character month) appear, is the same date really represented by two different values or is the date format the same for all dates?

Comment: Calls were not made for the hours absent

Comment: No its just 25thSep2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand the problem correctly, i think you should generate calendar dataset and join with first data set:

```
data have;
input callNumber Date $13. Hour Calls NextHour LastHour;
datalines4;
883  26thSep2019  7 14  .  .

885  25thSep2019  5  5  2  .

885  25thSept2019 2  4  1  5

885  25thSept2019 1  3  .  2

885  28thAug2019  3  5  7  .
;;;;
run;

proc sql noprint;
   create table dates as
   select distinct Date,CallNumber from have;
quit;


data calendar;
   set dates;
   do hour=0 to 23;
      output;
   end;
run;

proc sql noprint;
   create table want as
   select c.callNumber,
          c.Date,
          c.hour,
          (case
            when h.Hour is missing then 0
            else h.Calls
            end) as Calls
   from have h
   right join calendar c
   on c.date = h.date and c.hour = h.hour and c.callNumber = h.callNumber;
quit;
```

Input:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-------+----------+----------+
| callNumber |     Date     | Hour | Calls | NextHour | LastHour |
+------------+--------------+------+-------+----------+----------+
|        883 | 26thSep2019  |    7 |    14 |        . |        . |
|        885 | 25thSep2019  |    5 |     5 |        2 |        . |
|        885 | 25thSept2019 |    2 |     4 |        1 |        5 |
|        885 | 25thSept2019 |    1 |     3 |        . |        2 |
|        885 | 28thAug2019  |    3 |     5 |        7 |        . |
+------------+--------------+------+-------+----------+----------+
```

Output(part of dataset want):

```
+------------+-------------+------+-------+
| callNumber |    Date     | hour | Calls |
+------------+-------------+------+-------+
|        883 | 26thSep2019 |    0 |     0 |
|        883 | 26thSep2019 |    1 |     0 |
|        883 | 26thSep2019 |    2 |     0 |
|        883 | 26thSep2019 |    3 |     0 |
|        883 | 26thSep2019 |    4 |     0 |
|        883 | 26thSep2019 |    5 |     0 |
|        883 | 26thSep2019 |    6 |     0 |
|        883 | 26thSep2019 |    7 |    14 |
+------------+-------------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Hey Thanks I was able to get to the solution

Comment: Your solution helped thanks again . I used the proc freq data=Stage3 noprint;
    tables callNumber*Date*Hour/sparse out=want(drop=percent);
 where eventDate;
run; and then merged it with the main dataset.

Comment: @PreetiNareshAjwani if my solution helped then mark it as correct?:)

Answer (score 0):

A DOW loop can efficiently process groups with a minimal amount of syntax.

What's a DOW ?  The `set` and `by` are placed inside a `do` loop that has `until` criteria based on a `last.<by>` variable.

```
data want (keep=callNumber date hour calls);
  if 0 then set have; * prep pdv to have set vars first;
  array _calls (0:23) _temporary_;

  call missing (of _calls(*));
  do until (last.date);
    set have;
    by callNumber date;

    by callNumber date;
    _calls(hour) = sum (_calls(hour), calls);
  end;

  do hour = 0 to 23;
    calls = sum(0,_calls(hour));
    output;
  end;
run;
```